# I can't set the default options for the mysql command (v8.0.19) client in Windows 10. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, mysql, configuration, options

When I run `mysql --verbose --help` I get values that are different to those that are in my my.ini file. 
In particular, the following properties are set in my my.ini file (based on the recommendations in our company wiki) as follows:

```
max_allowed_packet=134217728
net_buffer_length=1000000
```

but when I run `mysql --verbose --help` I get:

```
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
```

I have checked the locations that the `mysql` command say it takes default options from:

```
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini 
C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf 
C:\my.ini 
C:\my.cnf 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.ini 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.cnf 
C:\opt\mysql-8.0.19-winx64\my.ini 
C:\opt\mysql-8.0.19-winx64\my.cnf
```

The only place where a file exists is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.ini`
I have updated the settings there, but `mysql --verbose --help` still outputs the original values.
What am I missing?

Comment: In which section of the ini file do you have this setting?

Comment: I wasn't aware there were sections, I just updated the first one in place, and appended the second one to the end of the file.

Comment: OK I see it now. That's what I get for just searching the file instead of reading it. Care to write an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql configuration file is ordered in sections. The various programs only read settings from their corresponding section.

The client reads the section `[client]`, so you need to place your settings under it:

```ini
[client]
max_allowed_packet=134217728
net_buffer_length=1000000
```

See [this excellent answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453913/212107) for more information.